# Unable to get rendered content error in SDL Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I would like to know the scenarios in which "Unable to get rendered content" error might occur in SDL Tridion. We use VBScript for templating and I get a few scenarios as listed below in my event logs. But I am not able to make head or tail of it.

Scenario 1:
Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:48-215280-64).

```
Error 5 occurred while rendering the Component Presentation (SMS gruppe:Artikkel): 
Invalid procedure call or argument: 'RemoveChild' (source:
        .RemoveChild .selectSingleNode("tcm).
```

Scenario 2:

```
Unable to get rendered content of Component (tcm:57-215271).
No data found. [ETA_ITEMS, U]
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ITEM_ID', table 'Tridion_cm_2011.dbo.ITEM_ASSOCIATIONS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Scenario 3:

```
Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:52-213774-64).
Error 1017 occurred while rendering the Page: Expected 'Then' (source:
   If Rendermode() != "PreviewDynamic" Then).
```

Scenario 4:

```
Unable to retrieve rendered data from Component Presentation.
Error 3004 occurred while rendering the Component Presentation (Nytt dagstilbud iPhone 4S:Artikkel): 
Write to file failed. (source:
              .SaveToFile strTempFile, conSaveCreateOverWrite).
```

Scenario 5:

```
Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:48-215164-64).
Error 3004 occurred while rendering the Component Presentation (Ring inn julen med Comoyo:Artikkel): 
Write to file failed. (source:
              .SaveToFile strTempFile, conSaveCreateOverWrite).
```

Scenario 6:

```
Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:48-215164-64).
Invalid value for property 'BinaryContent'. Unable to open uploaded file: C:\Windows\TEMP\tcm-48-215158square940.jpg.
```

It would be helpful if any of you could give me any clue as of where the problem might possibly be so that I could have a lead. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow @user1903749. Please consider joining the proposal for a Tridion-dedicated Stack Exchange website: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=m7p1FaPb-R6Nn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scenario 1 looks like a VBScript syntax error, so most likely a typo in your template code. Scenario 2 looks a bit more problematic, because its a database error. Scenario 3, 4, 5 and 6 all look like standard VBScript syntax errors again.

Some examples, Scenario 3:

```vb
If Rendermode() != "PreviewDynamic" Then
```

Has a syntax error and it mentions `Expected 'Then'` so we know the error is somewhere before the `Then` statement. Taking a closer look, you have parentesis behind the variable `RenderMode`, which is incorrect, it should be:

```vb
If RenderMode != "PreviewDynamic" Then
```

Comment: a typical reason why you would want to migrate VBScript Templates to Modular Templating, since you will not have the problem of syntax errors at runtime with C# assemblies or fragments anymore.

Comment: The "does not equal" operator in VBScript is "<>", not "!=". That's the reason for the error.

Comment: @John:Thanks a lot for your explanation. These syntax errors in templates are probably causing issues only at runtime because these are causing memory issues, probably off the top of my head, objects are being created but not released.

Comment: @Bart: Yes, We want to migrate to C# assemblies, but the application has been with VBScript and tridion 2009 for so long and just now we migrated it to 2011. Hopefully, our client gives a go-ahead for C# instead of VBScript. :)